# Which is the efficient way to convert a float into an int in python?

Tags: python, performance, int

I've been using `n = int(n)` to convert a `float` into an `int`.

Recently, I came across another way to do the same thing :

`n = n // 1`

Which is the most efficient way, and why?

Comment: @Srichakradhar: Sorry, I didn't understand... in the second way (using //) you are not converting a float to an int (at least in python 2.7), the result of this operation is still a float. So, in my understandment, you are comparing the performance of two different things...

Comment: @HugoCorrá `//` is always integer division, while `/` is contextual division (in Python 2) or real division (in Python 3 or in 2 with `from __future__ import division`).

Comment: @Kos: actually, `//` still returns a float, it's just floored.

Comment: @Kos `//` is always floor division, but its return type depends on the input types. `3.0 // 2` returns `1.0` for example.

Comment: @Kos even using from __future__ import division, the statement type(float() // 1) returns a float for me. So, I really don't understand what we are comparing here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Test it with `timeit`:

```
$ bin/python -mtimeit -n10000000 -s 'n = 1.345' 'int(n)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.234 usec per loop
$ bin/python -mtimeit -n10000000 -s 'n = 1.345' 'n // 1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.218 usec per loop
```

So floor division is only a faster by a small margin. Note that these values are *very* close, and I had to crank up the loop repeat count to iron out random influences on my machine. Even with such a high count, you need to repeat the experiments a few times to see how much the numbers still vary and what comes out faster *most* of the time.

This is logical, as `int()` requires a global lookup and a function call (so state is pushed and popped):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def use_int(n):
...     return int(n)
... 
>>> def use_floordiv(n):
...     return n // 1
... 
>>> dis.dis(use_int)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(use_floordiv)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE 
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

It is the `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `CALL_FUNCTION` opcodes that are slower than the `LOAD_CONST` and `BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE` opcodes; `LOAD_CONST` is a simple array lookup, `LOAD_GLOBAL` needs to do a dictionary lookup instead.

Binding `int()` to a local name can make a small difference, giving it the edge again (as it has to do less work than `// 1` floor division):

```
$ bin/python -mtimeit -n10000000 -s 'n = 1.345' 'int(n)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.233 usec per loop
$ bin/python -mtimeit -n10000000 -s 'n = 1.345; int_=int' 'int_(n)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.195 usec per loop
$ bin/python -mtimeit -n10000000 -s 'n = 1.345' 'n // 1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.225 usec per loop
```

Again, you need to run this with 10 million loops to see the differences consistently.

That said, `int(n)` is a lot more explicit and unless you are doing this in a time-critical loop, `int(n)` wins it in readability over `n // 1`. The timing differences are too small to make the cognitive cost of having to work out what `// 1` *does* here worthwhile.

Comment: Shouldn't you time this while `n = some_float` instead of `n = some_int` ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would `int` still be slower if you got rid of global lookup?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your correction, I deleted my answer. I promise next time I will know better :)

Comment: @InbarRose: Ick! That's a major mistake actually, as that makes things a little slower for `n // 1`...

Comment: @Kos: The difference would shrink, certainly.

Comment: @Kos: actually, using `timeit` it seems that using a global is faster than using a locally bound `int_`. Strange, still testing if I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I checked and got a nice result. Not really surprised, I'd expect `a//1` to do a tidbit more work than the function call.

Comment: For such minute calculations and times, results can be skewed depending on background processes. But it seems that both are almost equally efficient, and I would go with `int(n)` for readability.

Comment: A question if I may ask: `'int(n)', setup = 'n=1.232323'` is identical in time to `'int(1.232323)'`, so why is `'n // 1', setup = 'n=1.232323'` so different from `'1.232323 // 1'`?

Comment: @Roberto: The differences are sooo small; I do see differences between `int(n)` and `int(1.232323)`, but only across multiple runs.

Comment: for me `int(n)`, `n // 1` and `int(1.23232)` all fare around 2 secs for 10^7 repetitions... while `1.23232 // 1` takes only 0.22 secs for the same reps... I guess it's because it doesn't call any function or checks any name?

Comment: @Roberto: ah, peephole optimization: if you use `1.232323 // 1` the **compiler** calculates the outcome and *replaces* the bytecode with `LOAD_CONST(1)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oooh I cheated then!

Comment: @Roberto: In other words, the compiler sees you are running arithmetics on two constants, and just stores the outcome as a constant. You are testing how fast Python can look up that constant, not how fast you can calculate the floor division.

Comment: @MartijnPieters makes perfect sense! Thanks for your patience, I wish I could pay you back with molecular biology info, lol!

Comment: Sorry, but -1. For my first two trys, the answer is the exact opposite, and thus, it is not "logical" to me.

Comment: @phresnel: I updated the answer already; I was seeing some inconsistent results too, that's why I cranked up the repeat count some more. The margins are small here, so a disk flush or background task re-schedule by the OS all skew the results very quickly.

Comment: @phresnel: and I appreciate the feedback anyway; I do see that the timings are close enough that the result isn't always clear-cut. It is also knowledge of how the Python interpreter works that gives me the confidence to know my answer is correct here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: fabs(-1) :)

Answer (score 3):

Although Martijn Pieters answered your question of what is faster and how to test it I feel like speed isn't that important for such a small operation. I would use int() for readability as Inbar Rose said. Typically when dealing with something this small readability is far more important; although, a common equation can be an exception to this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `int` seems to be faster than the division. The slow part is looking the function up in the global scope.

Here are my numbers if we avoid it:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'i=int; a=123.456' 'i(a)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.122 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'i=int; a=123.456' 'a//1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.145 usec per loop
```

Comment: In Python 2.7, `n // 1` *still wins*.

Comment: Why `i=int` in second timeit?

Comment: @InbarRose: to reuse the command line? Doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the result comes from Python 2.7.3 on 32-bit Ubuntu, on Virtualbox. :)

Comment: For such minute calculations and times, results can be skewed depending on background processes. But it seems that both are almost equally efficient, and I would go with `int(n)` for readability.

Comment: @Kos: 2.7.5; Python 3.3.2 doesn't do any better.

Comment: `a // 1` wins in Python 2.7, it is about 6% faster. Difference is small but statistically it's there (I posted my code in an answer below if anyone wants to check...)

Answer (score 2):

### Too long; didn't read:

Using `float.__trunc__()` is 30% faster than `builtins.int()`

### I like long explanations:

@MartijnPieters trick to bind `builtins.int` is interesting indeed and it reminds me to [An Optimization Anecdote](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/). However, calling `builtins.int` is not the most efficient.

Let's take a look at this:

```
python -m timeit -n10000000 -s "n = 1.345" "int(n)"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 48.5 nsec per loop

python -m timeit -n10000000 -s "n = 1.345" "n.__trunc__()"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 33.1 nsec per loop
```

That's a 30% gain! What's happening here?

It turns out all `builtints.int` does is invoke the following [method-chains](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

- If `1.345.__int__` is defined return `1.345.__int__()` else:
- If `1.345.__index__` is defined return `1.345.__index__()` else:
- If `1.345.__trunc__` is defined return `1.345.__trunc__()`

`1.345.__int__` is not defined <sup>1</sup> - and neither is `1.345.__index__`. Therefore, directly calling `1.345.__trunc__()` allow us to skip all the unnecessary method calls - which is relatively expensive.

---

What about the binding trick? Well `float.__trunc__` is essentially just an instance method and we can pass `1.345` as the `self` argument.

```
python -m timeit -n10000000 -s "n = 1.345; f=int" "f(n)"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 43 nsec per loop

python -m timeit -n10000000 -s "n = 1.345; f=float.__trunc__" "f(n)"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 27.4 nsec per loop
```

Both methods improved as ***expected*** <sup>2</sup> and they maintain roughly the same ratio!

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not entirely certain about this - correct me if somebody knows otherwise.

<sup>2</sup> This surprised me because I was under the impression that `float.__trunc__` is binded to `1.345` during instance creation. It'd be great if anyone'd be kind enough to explain this to me.

---

There is also this method `builtins.float.__floor__` that is not mentioned in the documentation - and is faster than `builtins.int` but slower than `buitlins.float.__trunc__`.

```
python -m timeit -n10000000 -s "n = 1.345; f=float.__floor__" "f(n)"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 32.4 nsec per loop
```

It seems to produce the same results on both negative and positive floats. Would be awesome if someone could explain how this fits among the other methods.

Comment: Not including `//` here because it returns `float` not `int`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that **you are not converting from float to int** using the floor division operator. The result of this operation is still a float. In Python 2.7.5 (CPython), `n=n//1` is exactly the same thing of:

```
n.__floordiv__(1)
```

that is basically the same thing of:

```
n.__divmod__(1)[0]
```

both functions return a float instead of an int. Inside the CPython `__divmod__` function, the denominator and numerator must be converted from PyObject to double. So, in this case, it's faster to use the `floor` function instead of the `//` operator, because only one conversion is needed.

```
from cmath import floor
n=floor(n)
```

In the case you really want to convert a float to integer, I don't think there is a way to beat up the int(n) performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a statistical test to have a little fun - change the timeit tests to whatever you prefer:

```
import timeit
from scipy import mean, std, stats, sqrt

# Parameters:
reps = 100000
dups = 50
signif = 0.01
timeit_setup1 = 'i=int; a=123.456'
timeit_test1 = 'i(a)'
timeit_setup2 = 'i=int; a=123.456'
timeit_test2 = 'a//1'

#Some vars
t1_data = []
t2_data = []
frmt = '{:.3f}'
testformat = '{:<'+ str(max([len(timeit_test1), len(timeit_test2)]))+ '}'

def reportdata(mylist):
    string = 'mean = ' + frmt.format(mean(mylist)) + ' seconds, st.dev. = ' + \
             frmt.format(std(mylist))
    return string

for i in range(dups):
    t1_data.append(timeit.timeit(timeit_test1, setup = timeit_setup1,
                                    number = reps))
    t2_data.append(timeit.timeit(timeit_test2, setup = timeit_setup2,
                                    number = reps))

print testformat.format(timeit_test1) + ':', reportdata(t1_data)
print testformat.format(timeit_test2) + ':', reportdata(t2_data)
ttest = stats.ttest_ind(t1_data, t2_data)
print 't-test: the t value is ' + frmt.format(float(ttest[0])) + \
      ' and the p-value is ' + frmt.format(float(ttest[1]))
isit = ''
if float(ttest[1]) > signif:
    isit = "not "
print 'The difference of ' + \
      '{:.2%}'.format(abs((mean(t1_data)-mean(t2_data))/mean(t1_data))) + \
      ' +/- ' + \
      '{:.2%}'.format(3*sqrt((std(t1_data)**2 + std(t2_data)**2)/dups)) + \
      ' is ' + isit + 'significative.'
```

Comment: check out `pandas` and `ipython notebook` if you haven't yet :-)

Comment: So far I have only looked at what `pandas` is, because EVERYBODY asks questions about pandas here! It's on the to-do list :) Thanks!

Comment: oooh ipython notebook is pretty spiffy :>